# Integrity Error in Django 1.7

Tags: python, django, orm, primary-key

The following query throws an Integrity error when the about column is changed after first save. Primary key of page table is foreign key to pagedes table.

```
page_id1 = models.Page.objects.get(page= selected_page_by_user)
try:
   (save_des, check_des)= models.Pagedes.objects.update_or_create(page = page_id1, about = about, description = description)
except:
   print 'page data_desc save error'
```

Comment: can you post your error trace?

Comment: I'd also think it would be easier if you posted your models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call update_or_create with a changed "about" value and an existing primary key, this must throw an error. In case you want to do this you should pass your updated values to the defaults argument like shown in the [docu](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create):

```
obj, created = Person.objects.update_or_create(
    first_name='John', last_name='Lennon', defaults=updated_values)
```